# Regular expression for only numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression for only numbers not less and more than 4 digit and also it should not accept characters.

I tried this but it is accepting characters also

```
 var reg = /^\d{4,4}$/;
```

I want in JavaScript.

Comment: It should work, where is the problem. Do you get some errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use this,

```
^\d{4}$
```

It allows exactly 4 digits only. You don't need to specify the range.

Use the below regex if you want to allow 4 or more digits.

```
^\d{4,}$
```

Comment: `\d{4}` and `\d{4,4}` are strictly the same.

Comment: The preldoc site includes several tutorials. It's the reference. http://perldoc.perl.org/index.html If you want a book, Programing Perl is a good choice, written by Larry Wall, (O'Reilly edition)

Comment: @downvoter you could explain the reason for downvote?

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj; It worked for me, sorry for late voting as was busy with some other tasks.

Answer (score 3):

You *really* don't need a regex for that. All you need is this

```
if(!isNaN(Number(str)) && str.length == 4){
  // do something
}
```